# Typescript Class Import Error: Property 'prototype' is missing in type '<component name>' but required in type 'typeof <component name>'. TS(2741)

Tags: typescript

What attempting to import one component in to a second component I am receiving the following error.

> Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'InputComponent' but required
>   in type 'typeof InputComponent'. TS(2741)

test.ts

```js
class InputComponent {

  add():number{
    return 1 + 1
  }
}

class Example {
  public input: typeof InputComponent;

  constructor(Input: typeof InputComponent) {
    this.input = new Input();
  }
}

class Example2 {
  public input: typeof InputComponent;

  constructor(Input: typeof InputComponent = InputComponent) {
    this.input = new Input();
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the error and sandbox.

[typescript sandbox](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/MYGwhgzhAECSB2AHArgFwMIHsC2jPwFN5VoBvAWACgrpowATegCgEoAueZbAIwICcKlWrT4FUyPvGgBGaAGoZNaAF8qq6pVCQYAUQAeYXCAJklKbiACWwaJaRo20VAE9EBTADM49jDjyFiAG4qJWB8CFQ+ZGBUTD4mBBRURxc3T28krFx8IlQWUyFhVAALSwgAOjsk6ABeaEIAdwy0VmDC9XUqLShofUNEYwAmAtpzKxsqhydXdy9EtCz-XLbQ8Mjo2Pj55Om0uZ9FnOJa5t9sgLyRotKKyZI6xtPWpQ6gA)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The problem is you're referring with `public input` to `typeof InputComponent` but you're trying to assign a `new InputComponent()` to it.

Changing it to `public input: InputComponent` solves the problem.

In typescript `InputComponent` refers to an object of the class whereas `typeof InputComponent` refers to the class itself.

```js
class InputComponent {

  add():number{
    return 1 + 1
  }
}

class Example {
  public input: InputComponent;

  constructor(Input: typeof InputComponent) {
    this.input = new Input();
  }
}

class Example2 {
  public input: InputComponent;

  constructor(Input: typeof InputComponent = InputComponent) {
    this.input = new Input();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marvin, Your answer was so clear. Could be please state what's the difference between Public input : typeof InputComponent and Public input : InputComponent